# Regular Expression nested within Positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string (no new lines):

```
--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.0597&--&1&__&Lost Packets % (Period)&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&__&Maximum Lost Packets % (Period)&++&0.6000&--&1&++&0.7984&--&1&++&0.6000&--&1&++&0.0000&--&1&++&0.5988&--&1&__&Duplicate Packets&++&0&++&0&++&0&++&0&++&0&__
```

Using the following regex in Python:

```
(?<=&Lost Packets % \(Period\)).*(?=&Maximum Lost Packets % \(Period\))
```

I get the following output:

```
&++&1.0000&--&1&++&2.0000&--&1&++&3.0000&--&1&++&4.0000&--&1&++&5.0000&--&1&__
```

Now using the following regex `(?<=&\+\+&).*?(?=&--&1)` on the above output i get the following **1.0000 2.0000 3.0000 4.0000 5.0000**

This is the desire output.

My question been, is there a way to combine regex `(?<=&Lost Packets % \(Period\)).*(?=&Maximum Lost Packets % \(Period\))` and regex `(?<=&\+\+&).*?(?=&--&1)` into one?

Tried a few different thinks but failed.

Comment: Use the `|` operator, `<pattern1>|<pattern2>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. I didn't know you could pipe in regex. I did a quick test on regex101.com and found that `pattern2` gets apply to the entire string not to the substring from `pattern1`. Any suggestions as to what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Then it is a bit more difficult. I would not merge these patterns in Python `re`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just check the ref guided `|`is an `OR` not a pipe as i originally though. This would be why it dose not work